# Relative homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

The local homology of a manifold $X$ at a point $x$ is defined as the relative homology $H_n(X, X-{x};\ \mathbb Z)$. It holds true for relative homology that under certain conditions $H(X,A) = H(X/A)$. For example it is satisfied for connected smooth surfaces like a torus. But doesn't it mean that $X/(X - \{x\})= x$? And if so, the $H_n(X, X-{x})$ is just the homology of a point? Please help me figure out possible mistakes in my geometric thinking.

Answer (score 6):

The conditions you mention in order for $H_n(X,A)=\tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ is that the closure of $A$ has a neighbourhood which deformation retracts on to $A$. This is not possible in the case $A=X\setminus\{x\}$ for obvious reasons. Therefore the condition is not satisfied. Also, the space $X/(X\setminus\{x\})$ is a topological space with two points $\{x\}$ and $X\setminus\{x\}$, and (assuming $X$ is a manifold) has the homeomorphism type of [the Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).

Comment: Isn't $\{X-\{x\}\}$ an open set in the quotient space? I think it has the Sierpinski topology.

Comment: @StefanH. Ah yes you're right.In that case $X/(X\setminus\{x\})$ is the Sierpinski space. That's pretty cool.

Comment: Also note that if $A$ is open, it has a neighborhood which deformation retracts onto $A$, namely $A$ itself. What you mean is of course that the closure of $A$ has such a neighborhood.

Comment: @StefanH. Also a very important correction. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! If the relative homology is not really like $X/X-\{x\}$ what is a good substitute intuition?

Comment: What we do have (by excision) is an isomorphism $H_n(X,X\setminus\{x\})\cong H_n(U,U\setminus\{x\})$ for a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. In particular, for $m$-manifolds we just get $H_n(X,X\setminus\{x\})\cong H_n(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^m \setminus\{0\}) \cong \tilde{H}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{0\})\cong\tilde{H}_{n-1}(S^{m-1})$ which is trivial unless $n=m$ when it is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @snailspace: Yes, as Daniel said, excision localizes this for you (like choosing a chart). But think about a relative $n$-cycle as an $n$-chain "covering" $x$ and whose boundary is away from $x$. As is often the case with orientation classes, thinking simplicially is helpful.