# Hatcher, Thm 2.13

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> **Theorem 2.13.** If $X$ is a space and $A$ is a nonempty *closed* subspace that is a deformation retract of some neighborhood in $X$, then there is an exact sequence $$\cdots \longrightarrow \tilde H_n (A)\longrightarrow \tilde H_n(X) \longrightarrow \tilde H_n(X/A)\longrightarrow \tilde H_{n-1}(A)\longrightarrow \cdots $$

What's bugging me is the requirement $A$ be closed - isn't it enough to ask $\overline A\subset \mathring V$?

I ask the same question for the theorem stated in [this homework sheet](http://math.harvard.edu/~hirolee/pdfs/231a-hmwk03.pdf):

> **Theorem 0.2.** Let $A\subset X$ be a *closed* subset such that $A$ is a deformation retract of some open set $V\subset X$. Then there is an isomorphism $$H(X,A)\cong H(X/A,\text{pt})$$

Isn't it enough to ask $\overline A\subset \mathring V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the proof of proposition 2.22 in Hatcher's book, you see that there's a sequence of isomorphisms, some of which are valid by excision, and one of which is the map $H_n(X-A,V-A)\longrightarrow H_n(X/A-A/A,V/A-A/A)$ induced by the restriction of the quotient map $q:X\to X/A$ to the subspace $X-A$. You are right that excision works as long as we have $\overline A\subseteq \mathring V$. However, this restriction of $q$ to $X-A$ need not be a homeomorphism, but it certainly is when $A$ is closed (or open).

Comment: Thank you, you pinpointed the issue. To show $q|_{A^c}\rightarrow (X/A)\setminus (A/A)$ given by $b\mapsto [b]={b}$ is a homeomorphism I must show it is bijective and bicontinuous. I (falsely of course) concluded this function is a homeomorphism regardless of whether $A$ is closed or open. I see why it is bijective, but as a corestriction of a continuous map, I think I'm not sure why it is continuous. Is this the part which requires $A$ to be open or closed (as a sufficient condition)?

Comment: @Exterior: A restriction of a continuous map is always continuous. And if $A$ is closed, then $q|_{X-A}$ is an open map because when $U\subseteq X-A$ is open in $X-A$, then $U$ is open and saturated in $X$, so $q(U)$ is open. In case, $A$ is open, you can use closed sets of $X-A$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you elaborate a little on what 'saturated' means and how it's relevant?

Comment: @Exterior: 'Saturated' means that $B=q^{-1}(q(B))$. In a quotient space a set is open if and only if it's the image of an open saturated set (the same holds with open replaced by closed).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In the first answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457240/relative-homology-groups) question, the author seems to say it suffices for $\overline A$ to have a neighborhood that deformation retracts to $A$ - without necessarily being closed - to have $H_n(X,A)=\tilde{H}_n(X/A)$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Also, are the results in my question both correct if one stipulates $A$ is open instead of closed?

Comment: @Exterior: I'm not sure whether the map $H_n(X-A,V-A)\longrightarrow H_n(X/A-A/A,V/A-A/A)$ is still an isomorphism if $A$ is neither open nor closed. But I will think about it.